# Watch mode for multiple child workspaces in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tsc, monorepo

I have the following project structure:

```
├── foo                   (workspace @project/foo)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── index.ts
├── bar                   (workspace @project/bar)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── index.ts
├── package.json          (monorepo root)
└── tsconfig.json         (base tsconfig)
```

If I run `tsc --watch` in each child workspace, TypeScript watches the file changes correctly and rebuilds the package. However, If I run the same command at the monorepo root, it doesn't work - it doesn't throw an error but if I change anything in file, the package is not rebuilt.

Reading the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#build-mode-for-typescript), I understand that the `--build` flag does have an option to pass multiple child projects (or `tsconfig.json` files). Is there something equivalent for `--watch`?